# document.getElementById("tweetform").submit is not a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm using Firefox and I've been reading some forums claiming this doesn't work in firefox but it has been working for me for the last few days but has stopped working and I can not figure out why.

I make a AXAX POST Request using an IFrame. When I get the response I use this:

```
function startLoad(){
    $.get("update.php", function(data){
            if(data==''){
                startLoad();
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("tweetform").submit();
            }
    });
}
```

However, from firebug, I get this:

```
document.getElementById("tweetform").submit is not a function
[Break on this error] document.getElementById("tweetform").submit();
```

I know submit exists, but what is going on?

Comment: Does the element tweetform exist? Is it a form?

Comment: Can you alert(document.getElementById("tweetform")) and check whether it returns a form?

Comment: Yes, tweetform exists and that alert returns: [object HTMLFormElement]

Comment: What does alert(document.getElementById("tweetform").submit) show?

Comment: Why are you using "document.getElementById" when you are using jQuery? Why not just use "$('#tweetform')"?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

My *guess* would be that you have an element in the form that is called "submit" (possibly a `<button>` or `<input type="submit">`, and that ".submit" is retrieving a reference to that element, rather than the member function "submit()". If this is the case, try renaming that element to something else (e.g., "submit_button").

Comment: Good call. I have been bitten by this before.

Comment: We have a genius here! :) You are right, I had a button with name attribute "submit"! But what is the use of getElementById if it doesn't reference that element! :P

Comment: It does. Your problem is that `myForm.submit` is another element and not a function that submits the form.

Comment: i love stackoverflow for this. you cant find this answer in a documentation. just experience can give it to you

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was an img with an attribute id="submit"

Comment: renamed my field with <input type='submit' name='form_submit'.. to avoid the error :)

Answer (score 5):

**Jason Musgrove** explained the issue well.

You can use a native **submit** method of HTMLFormElement to work around a problem:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call($('#tweetform')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually its enough to rename your <input name="submit" /> to something else and it works.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are using jQuery.

Try this instead.

```
$("#tweetform").submit();
```

Comment: That is the same as document.getElementById("tweetform"), so if that fails, running the jQuery equivalent does not make a difference.

Comment: well.. this kind of error that the guy had wouldn't have happend using the syntax that I recommended.

Comment: I don't believe it — but I'll test just to make sure — and I'm right. It wouldn't fix it.

Comment: -1. Also, don't use jQuery.submit() together with forms validation, say doing an $("tweetform_button").click(function(){...//code here; $("tweetform").submit() }); You'll get an infinite loop

Answer (score -4):

Use document.forms['tweetform'].submit() instead

Comment: Accessing the HTMLFormElement object a different way isn't going to make the submit method magically start working.