# Why can't I manually submit this form?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to get something done before my form submits. The following code runs through without errors, but my form never gets submitted. I can't tell what's wrong..

```
<form method="post" id="weber-form" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl">
    <input class="textInputaweb" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="20" value='Enter Email'  onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Enter Email' ) { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Email';} " />
    <input id="submit" name="submit" class="submitaweber" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Do something...
            $('#weber-form').submit();
        });
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Need to see markup, probably.

Comment: Post some more code/markup...

Comment: @Yarin try this : $('form#weber-form').submit(); **OR** you can also bing your form like this - $('#myform').bind('submit', function(){ ... });  lemme know how it goes, cheers

Comment: Added markup. @Tats_innit- sorry your suggestion didn't help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for the following script to work, [the submit button must **NOT** have a `name` or `id` with the value "submit"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100932/575527). a button like this will work:

```
<input class="submitaweber" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MYht8/

```
$(function() {

    //we bind to the form instead of the form button
    //using .on() (jQ1.7+)
    $('#weber-form').on('submit', function(e) {

        //prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        //do stuff

        //use the native submit so we wont trigger 
        //this handler again
        this.submit();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Use your code within `document.ready()` section. I hope it will work!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // Do something...  
       $('#weber-form').submit();
     });
});
```

Comment: I've changed your answer to the working version- it needed the document.ready AND the .click function. Finally working- thanks

Comment: SHT nevermind- this isn't preventing it either.. I need to go to sleep guys sorry... try in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It should work.

> $('#weber-form').submit(function (e) {
>
> ```
> e.preventDefault();
>
> // Do something...
>
> $('#weber-form').submit();
> ```
>
> });

Comment: @Yarin - Since its a submit button, it first invokes a click event,then a submit event.. You were initially preventing by default the click event and not the submit event.. SO the click event was prevented but not the submit event..

Comment: Actually, nevermind this doesn't work after all- it simply doesn't prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: @Yarin - if you are putting this script into an external file then you will have to use $(document).ready()..

Comment: @Gopesh- that makes no difference. Please use a different comment thread or answer, this one is for Priyank's answer

Comment: @Priyank- it's not in an external file and doc.ready doesn't make a diff

Answer (score 1):

**Joseph the Dreamer** explained the issue well.

You can use a native **submit** method of HTMLFormElement to work around a problem:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call($('#weber-form')[0]);
```