# Submit on change() not working

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a field which lets the user change the number of results on the page, the plan is that the form is submitted to update the results if they change the page size.

```
<form id="js-selectionForm" class="simple_form" method="get" action="/knowledge/contaminants.php">
<div class="pad-5">
...
</div>

<div class="pad-5">
...
</div>

<div class="pad-5">
...
</div>

<div class="pad-5">
...
</div>

<div class="pad-5">
    <input class="button pad-2" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
    <h3 class="text-purple inline-block margin-10-left">
        Please select search criteria above                    </h3>
    <label class="right">Page size:
        <input class="refreshPage" type="number" name="pageSize" min="1" max="100"
               title="The number of results per page - 1 to 100"
               value="25"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

My jQuery includes the following;

```
$('.refreshPage').change(function () {
    $("#js-selectionForm").submit();
});
```

I know this selection works because I have put in console.log statements to check but the form is never submitted.  I have used similar code before and it has always worked so I must be doing something wrong here, can anybody help me spot my mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't the form method be 'post'?

Comment: is your page refreshing?

Comment: You cannot have any element with the `name` or `id` "submit".

Comment: @Ivar seems to be correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765695/why-cant-i-manually-submit-this-form#answer-9766435

Comment: @Kris Is there a reason why should the method be post?  GET seems to work except for this submission problem

Comment: @Mark_1 For a search form, a `GET` is fine.

Comment: @Mark_1 no, it was just a idea...

Comment: OK thanks, it looks like @Ivar is correct but now the value of the submit button isn't being passed as a parameter

Comment: check here https://jsfiddle.net/teL2fe8f/1/ I have fix this by changing the name and id of submit button

Comment: @Mark_1 You can add a hidden input field with a name and value of your choice to fix that.

Comment: That does it; thanks @Ivar would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept the final version?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to `.submit()`; see:

`$('.refreshPage').change(function () {
    $("#submit").click();
});`

PS - you're missing a `<form />` at the end. This could be why it's not working. Your code seems correct to me.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the `.submit()` isn't working.

Comment: broken form tag

Comment: That is not the problem.

Comment: @jtrein The </form> is there but for some reason not displaying on the stackoverflow page

Answer (score 0):

As per @Ivar's suggestion, change `name` and `id` of the submit input

```js
$('.refreshPage').change(function () {
    $("#js-selectionForm").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="js-selectionForm" class="simple_form" method="get" action="/knowledge/contaminants.php">

<div class="pad-5">
    <input class="button pad-2" id="submitMe" type="submit" name="submitMe" value="Search" />
    <h3 class="text-purple inline-block margin-10-left">
        Please select search criteria above                    </h3>
    <label class="right">Page size:
        <input class="refreshPage" type="number" name="pageSize" min="1" max="100"
               title="The number of results per page - 1 to 100"
               value="25" />
    </label>
</div>
</form>
```